# Force PostgreSQL not to think beyond what EXPLAIN says

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, explain

EXPLAIN gives a good strategy but nevertheless the query (and EXPLAIN ANLALYZE) runs extremely slowly.

Is there a simple way to force PostgreSQL *always* query by the same plan that EXPLAIN produces for a given query?

Comment: You're thinking about it backwards; `explain` always shows the actual plan Postgres will use to execute the query.

Comment: @mustaccio If it is so, then why is EXPLAIN ANALYZE needed?

Comment: EXPLAIN without ANALYZE doesn't actually run the query.  So it had better be faster.

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` shows the actual execution metrics, while the simple `EXPLAIN` only shows estimates that the optimizer uses.